# extra argument in call when creating NSManagedObjectModel

Tags: swift

I don't really understand why I'm getting an error in my map method.  The error is extra argument in call.

This works:

```
let url1 = NSURL(string: "123");
let url2 = NSURL(string: "456");
NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL:url1!);
```

When I try to use map for an array of NSURLs,

```
func createModels(test: [NSURL]) -> [NSManagedObjectModel]  {
    let newData = test.map {
        (url) -> NSURL in
        NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: url!); // errors here
    }
    return newData
}
```

So in the first snippet, I know that I can create a NSManagedObjectModel with that method call.  But when I try to do it with the map function for an array of NSURLs, it gives me an error of extra argument in call. Any thoughts?

Comment: Shouldn't `(url) -> NSURL` be `(url) -> NSManagedObject`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mapping closure takes an URL as *argument* and *returns* the model,
so the signature should be

```
(url: NSURL) -> NSManagedObjectModel
```

And

```
NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: url!); // errors here
```

is wrong because `url` is not an optional here. On the other hand,
`NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: url)` returns an optional
which needs to be unwrapped.

Putting it together:

```
func createModels(test: [NSURL]) -> [NSManagedObjectModel]  {
    let newData = test.map {
        (url: NSURL) -> NSManagedObjectModel in
        return NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: url)!
    }
    return newData
}
```

or with shorthand parameter notation:

```
func createModels(test: [NSURL]) -> [NSManagedObjectModel]  {
    let newData = test.map {
        NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOfURL: $0)!
    }
    return newData
}
```

Comment: Doesn't map return another array?  Shouldn't the compiler say it should be `(url) -> [NSManagedObjectModel]`?

Comment: @Crystal: `map()` transforms an array of type `[A]` into a new array of type `[B]`. It does that by applying the closure to each individual element of the given array. Therefore the closure has the type `A -> B`.